# Background Worker Result object is null after adding object with strings

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am making a simple `WinForms` program that should get a response from a website and measure the time needed to process.

I don't get is why `e.Result` is null after doing this: `e.Result = obj;`

I got the web request code from the MSDN site, but I'm not sure if it's correctly implemented.

This is for starting background worker:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Class for handling strings:

```
    public class TestObject
    {
        public string Request { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
    }
```

DoWork method:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
         TestObject obj = new TestObject();

        var stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        obj.Request = webResponse();

        stopwatch.Stop();

        obj.Time = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();


        e.Result = obj;
    }
```

RunWorkerCompleted method:

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestObject test = e.Result as TestObject;
        label1.Text = test.Request + test.Time;
    }
```

Web request code

```
    private string webResponse()
    {
        // Create a request for the URL.        
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.tvz.hr");

        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.

        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        // Read the content. 
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // Cleanup the streams and the response.
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        return responseFromServer;
    }
```

EDIT: This is the error that shows up https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGsxO.jpg
I have edited the Stopwatch part.
I think that `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` could be the problem. After it finishes, the `IsBusy` parameter of `backgroundWorker1` is True. And immediately after the `RunWorkerCompleted` starts and `IsBusy` is False

EDIT2: Solved, `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` wasnt typed in DoWork property in Properties window. I dont know how that happened, i have generated `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` method in Properties windows in the first place. Anyway, it works now. Thanks on all the help!

Comment: Can you describe the actual problem better? What's the exception? Linennumber?

Comment: Your entire `webRespones()` can be replaced by a single call to `WebClient.DownloadString()`

Comment: Exception is NullReferenceException at `label1.Text = test.Request + test.Time;` in RunWorkerCompleted method

Comment: Then use the debugger. Your code has several problems but none that would produce a `null` here.

Comment: (continuing here). Did the messagebox at the start of Completed show up?  And do check `label1` too.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes, box shows up. I think that whole `DoWork` function gets skipped because i cant get it to show up while debugging. I even put breakpoints in it and it still doesnt show up. Maybe this part is wrong `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();` I hope you understand what i mean with "doesnt show up while debugging", my english isnt very good :D

Comment: Make sure that either your code or Designer.cs executes `backgroundWorker1.DoWork += backgroundWorker1_DoWork;`

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ive solved the problem, check my last edit for info. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You should post that last part as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `e.Result` property within your `RunWorkerCompleted` will be null if an exception occurs during your `DoWork` handler or if the operation was cancelled, but fetching it should raise a `TargetInvocationException` if an error occurred.

Check [`e.Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error.aspx) to see if there is an exception, and [`e.Cancelled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.cancelled.aspx) to check for cancellation.

On a side note, I suspect your `Timer` object should actually be a [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx).  The `Timer` class is meant to schedule events to run, not measure timings.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    var stopwatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    TestObject obj = new TestObject();
    obj.Request = webResponse();
    stopwatch.Stop();
    obj.Time = stopwatch.Ellapsed.ToString();
    e.Result = obj;
}
```

Comment: Reading `e.Result` when there has been an exception will throw that exception.

Comment: @HenkHolterman True - but it's not clear if "it's null" means he's getting a NullReferenceException or reading the value of null...

Comment: Thanks on info! I forgot to mention that im getting NullReferenceException at label1.Text = test.Request + test.Time; in RunWorkerCompleted method

Comment: @imot01 When you debug - is the "test' variable null, or label1?

Comment: @Henk Holterman It doesnt. There is no such methods as e.Error and e.Cancelled

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes, you are right. I was trying to get them in DoWork. I added if's for e.Error and e.Cancelled but they dont show anything

Comment: @imot01 Check to see if `e.Result` is actually null, and not `test` - that would let you know if the "as" statement is failing...?

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yea, `e.Result` is null. I have added if before `TestObject test = e.Result as TestObject;`

Comment: @imot01 - that does not rhyme with your code. Please be very exact with the diagnostics and post the actual exception.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I said before, im getting Null reference exception. e.Result is still null after adding `TestObject obj` at `e.Result = obj;` Here is screenshot of error [link](http://i.imgur.com/Sb5BDFe.jpg)